# Trying to develop a Jquery slider savings calculator and am stuck

Tags: jquery

http://cdpn.io/AafGc

http://codepen.io/jakedx6/pen/AafGc

I haven't ever really tried to code anything like this in Jquery before and im sure my code is a mess but I would appreciate some help on making it work. The link above is to a CodePen of my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: One huge thing that might do it, it should be `$(this)` not `$("this")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to calculate with strings like `$5,000` and that's not possible because it's not a number (`NaN`).

If you remove the `$` char your code works as expected:

```
var totalcoan = $( "#tviytviy" ).val().substring(1);
var totalvfiy = $( "#totalcoan" ).val().substring(1);
```

[I updated your code.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LcarC)

You should also use `$(this)` instead of `$("this")` because you want to select the object and not the DOM tag `this`.

Comment: I got it to work I did it slightly differently, would love for you to look at it and give any other advise Thanks for you help!
http://codepen.io/jakedx6/pen/GAmCo